# sed: region followed by number

Tags: regex, sed, escaping

Consider the following line:

```
install --with-some-params some_pkg_name.10000
install --with-some-params other_pkg_name.10000
install --with-some-params yet_other_pkg_name.10000
```

I'm trying to change the file so that every line that installs `some_pkg_name` would upgrade to another version - say, `10001`. I've tried:

```
sed 's/\(install --with-some-params some_pkg_name\.\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1 10001/g'
```

This indeed matches the right line, but enters an unnecessary space:

```
install --with-some-params some_pkg_name. 10001
                                         ^
install --with-some-params other_pkg_name.10000
install --with-some-params yet_other_pkg_name.10000
```

But if I omit the space in the regex, it matches region `\110001`, instead of `\1` followed by `10001`.

Is there any way to part the `1` from the `10001`, without adding spaces between them in the output?

Comment: hmm it works here. weird

Comment: @Adam: Are you sure? Regarding `sed`s `man` page there are only capture groups `\1` to `\9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround is to move out the dot from the group:

```
sed 's/\(install --with-some-params some_pkg_name\)\.\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1.10001/g'
```

Comment: That was my first attempt, but it is not as robust as I want it to be.

Comment: huh? robust? what's the problem?

Comment: I can not be 100% sure that the dot will always be the separator.

Comment: then tell us what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest a solution with other tool that takes these kind of task in a similar way but with more power, `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(install --with-some-params some_pkg_name\.)(\d{5})/$1 . ($2+1)/e' infile
```

Result:

```
install --with-some-params some_pkg_name.10001
install --with-some-params other_pkg_name.10000
install --with-some-params yet_other_pkg_name.10000
```

The `/e` flag lets you evaluate the replacement part, incrementing the number version in one.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to place what you're replacing with in single quotes so:

```
sed 's/\(install --with-some-params some_pkg_name\.\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1'10001'/g'
```

Comment: this is identical to his command line. the shell will concatenate the strings.

Comment: I had the same error, having added in the single quotes works for me fine. This is in GNU sed 4.2.1

Comment: well it definitely shouldn't make any difference. are you sure his example didn't work on your machine? (I have sed 4.2.1 too!)

Comment: Positive, the example provided gave the same output as the issue he was having. The addiction of single quotes removed the space.

Comment: I know how the shell works, those extra quotes cannot make it behave differently. sed will never see them. period.

Comment: I can appreciate your experience however, in my use/case this is the case. If you wish to experiment with this please do so however, as I have stated, in the version I use:

    $ sed 's/\(install --with-some-params some_pkg_name\.\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1 10001/g' temp
    install --with-some-params some_pkg_name. 10001
    $ sed 's/\(install --with-some-params some_pkg_name\.\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)/\1'10001'/g' temp
    install --with-some-params some_pkg_name.10001

This may be due to this sed version and how it parses the regex, please do not accuse if you have not attempted in the same use/case.

Comment: hehe.. just remove the space and you'll see it works fine. so it has nothing to do with the quotes.